# Apple Numeric Keyboard can't render the at sign "@" on Mac Mini

Tags: keyboard

I just got a new numeric keyboard for my Mac Mini but when I press `Shift + 2`, I don't get the at sign (@)--instead, it's a double quote. Then, `Shift + 4` shows a euro instead of `$`, `Shift + 6` an ampersand (&) instead of a `^`, etc. How do I fix this?

Comment: Which language is set for your Mac Mini?

Comment: I just saw now from the Input Sources that "Danish" is checked but for some reason the checkbox is disabled. I'm following this tutorial: www.wikihow.com/Change-the-Language-of-a-Mac

Answer (score 1):

I checked "US," then the checkbox beside "Danish" was enabled, then I unchecked it.